# Jackson. Как десериализовать конкретное поле, а не весь класс?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

В процессе изучения `RESTful` технологии возник вопрос, как же красиво обрабатывать тело в `http` запросе. Заметил что очень часто используют `Jackson`, но тут возник вопрос, как через него отправить конкретное поле в `JSON` формате?

Если с классом все хорошо и я могу его завернуть и отправить:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(UserObj);
//{"id":10,"name":"Vasya"}
```

То как решить ситуацию, когда меня просят вернуть просто имя: `{"name":"Vasya"}`???

Comment: посмотри модули `dil`l `hdf5`

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `@JsonView` и интерфейсов-маркеров

```
// маркеры
public class Views {
    public static class Short {
    }
}

public class UserObj {
    public int id;

    @JsonView(Views.Short.class)
    public String name;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// полная сериализация
String fullView = mapper
      .writeValueAsString(user);

// выборочная
String shortView = mapper
      .writerWithView(Views.Short.class)
      .writeValueAsString(user);
```